# Flutter :Future builder doesn't gets the data

Tags: firebase, flutter

I wrote this code which queries Firebase database and returns some data. This thing was working totally fine till few days back but i don't know why now it returns "no data" even if i have data in the database

Is there a error in the code or Something else cause this ?

> Fetching the data from Firebase

```
getsearchfood(String query) {
   Future<QuerySnapshot> search =
   Firestore.instance.collection("data").getDocuments();
   setState(() {
     searched = search;
   });
 }
```

> Operating the data

```
  buildsearchfood() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: searched,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
            print("no data");
        }
        else{
            print("present data");
        }
        return Container(
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: I just restated the emulator, and it’s good now

Answer (score 0):

Add await, as it is an asynchronous operation

```
Future<QuerySnapshot> search =
   await Firestore.instance.collection("data").getDocuments();
```

Comment: It’s of Future<Querysnapshot> Type and I have a future builder there so I am afraid it won’t work

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `setState` like you did.

Try this:

```
buildsearchfood() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: Firestore.instance.collection("data").getDocuments(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          // This means you have data. You can reference it in `snapshot.data`
        }
        else{
          // This means NO data
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: You need to either handle the Documents list returned from `getDocuments` or return the list as `snapshots` and mold them into the widgets that you want

Comment: can you please try this code in one of your projects